# Detecting when user presses enter in Java

Tags: java, events, swing, jcombobox, keylistener

I have a subclass of JComboBox. I attempt to add a key listener with the following code.

```
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() 
        {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt)
            {
                if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    System.out.println("Pressed");
                }
            }
        });
```

This however does not correctly detect when the user presses a key. It is actually not called at all. Am I adding this listener wrong? Are there other ways to add it?

Comment: please show us full code, and may I know why tracking enter press in combobox is needed ?

Comment: the function doesn't seem to have a problem, maybe the way you invoke it has something wrong. We need to see more of the code

Comment: @user489041, you should not be using a KeyListener for this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Key events aren't fired on the box itself, but its editor. You need to add the keyListener to the editor of the JComboBox and not the box directly:

```
comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() 
    {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt)
        {
            if(evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
            {
                System.out.println("Pressed");
            }
        }
    });
```

Edit: fixed method call.

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT the proper approach. The editor for a JComboBox is a JTextField. If you want to handle the Enter key then you add an ActionListener to the text field.

Always avoid using KeyListeners.

Edit:

```
comboBox.getEditorComponent().addActionListener( ... );
```

Comment: @user489041, have you ever added an ActionListener to a JButton? Well the code is exactly the same. If you haven't then read the section from the Swing tutorial on "How to Write an Action Listener" (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html).

Comment: You need comboBox.getEditor().addActionListener(...)