# my jComboBox does not react to my keyListener and actionPerform performs weired stuff

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, listeners, comboboxmodel

I am trying to search for UserName and return values onto jComboBox, here is the code

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
    sr = new Search(((String) jComboBoxReceiver.getSelectedItem()));    
    usrList = sr.searchUser();
    String[] userList = new String[usrList.size()] ;
    for(int i=0;i<usrList.size();i++){
        userList[i]= usrList.get(i).getUserName();
    }
    model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(userList);
    jComboBoxReceiver.setModel(model);
}
```

after you click to somewhere else or click enter,it will conduct the search, however, it will go search for the first item again, which is very confusing... then i tried using key Pressed

```
if(e.getKeyCode()==13){
    sr = new Search(((String) jComboBoxReceiver.getSelectedItem()));    
    usrList = sr.searchUser();
    String[] userList = new String[usrList.size()] ;
    for(int i=0;i<usrList.size();i++){
        userList[i]= usrList.get(i).getUserName();
    }
    model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(userList);
    jComboBoxReceiver.setModel(model);
}
```

And this one does not react at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, you're rebuilding a ComboBoxModel each time ? Isn't it a little expensive ? You know there is a [`MutableComboBoxModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/MutableComboBoxModel.html), also implemented by `DefaultComboBoxModel` that would allow you to add/remove elements from you combobox without rebuilding its model each time ?

Concerning your question, I don't understand the statement

> However, if i do that, it does perform correctly, however, it will go search for the first item again

Do you mean your JComboBox starts to blink with content being modified each time ?

if so, maybe is it because your `ActionListener` is linked to `JComboBox`, which content changes continuously.

Anyway, i suggest you add some logs, like

```
sr = new Search(((String) jComboBoxReceiver.getSelectedItem()));    
DefaultComboBoxModel model = (DefaultComboBoxModel) jComboBoxReceiver.getModel();
model.remvoeAllElements();
usrList = sr.searchUser();
String[] userList = new String[usrList.size()] ;
for(int i=0;i<usrList.size();i++){
    String username = usrList.get(i).getUserName();
    System.out.println(username); // feel free to instead use one loger
    model.addElement(username);
}
```

Besides, i would tend to suggest you an other approach, in which combo box model don't contain simple Strings, but rather User objects, with a [`ListCellRenderer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) displaying only the user name.

Comment: Thanks a lot... problem is , our lecturers only teach us basic concepts, ListcellRenderer and MutableModelEvent is kinda too complicated ... haha

Comment: Excuse me for being that rude, but you know, all those Javadocs are directly available from JComboBox page. As a consequence, as a professional developper, I **do expect you** to read those documentations and use them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the listener(s) on the Editor not the ComboBox itself. See the answer here:

[Detecting when user presses enter in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673350/detecting-when-user-presses-enter-in-java/4673371#4673371)

Answer (score 1):

IMO, what will really be confusing for your users is to have the content and selection of a combo box changed as soon as they select one of its options.

Anyway, if you really want to do that, then you should remove the action listener (or deactivate it) before changing its content, and re-add it (or reactivate it) after :

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
    sr = new Search(((String) jComboBoxReceiver.getSelectedItem()));    
    usrList = sr.searchUser();
    String[] userList = new String[usrList.size()] ;
    for(int i=0;i<usrList.size();i++){
        userList[i]= usrList.get(i).getUserName();
    }
    model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(userList);
    jComboBoxReceiver.removeActionListener(this);
    jComboBoxReceiver.setModel(model);
    jComboBoxReceiver.addActionListener(this);
}
```