# Run same function when clicking and pressing enter key

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have this function that runs when clicking on a button, but I want to run the same function when pressing enter. How should I do this?

```
@FXML
public void login(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    if(txtUName.getText().equals("jesse") && txtPass.getText().equals("essej")){
        Parent home;
        try {
            home = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Home.fxml"));
            Scene homeScene = new Scene(home);

            Stage window = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();

            window.setScene(homeScene);

            window.show();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }else {
        lblError.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to google something like "How to handle key event in JavaFX"?

Comment: @Gnas Yes, but I need a mouse click event and a key event.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javafx: How to bind the Enter key to a button and fire off an event when it is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32038418/javafx-how-to-bind-the-enter-key-to-a-button-and-fire-off-an-event-when-it-is-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution for me.

You can set the button as a Default Button in Scene Builder so when you press enter it also activates the method.

Answer (score 0):

You need a key event, this event should then be check it is "enter" which was pushed.

[Detecting when user presses enter in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673350/detecting-when-user-presses-enter-in-java#4673371)

Comment: Is it possible to do this in the same function, instead of making two functions for ActionEvent and one KeyEvent.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible, but you can create a separate function to contain all of your logic, then call it in both event handlers.

Comment: On second thought it might be possible to change the signature of your handler to receive an `Event` object instead of `ActionEvent` so you can assign it to both mouse and key events.

Comment: @Gnas extract logic and call that from each of the handlers is the way to go, no need for fancy stuff: that would be just additional work with additional occasions to introduce bug ;)

Comment: @kleopatra yep, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you have another @FXML function that you want to do the same? Just put your logic in a separate function and call it from your event functions.

```
@FXML
public void buttonPressed(MouseEvent event) {
    doSomething(event);
}

@FXML
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
    doSomething(event);
}

private void doSomething(InputEvent event) {
    // your code here
}
```

This KeyEvent and MouseEvent inherit from [InputEvent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/InputEvent.html). You can still call  `.getSource()` because it's inherited and in the code you've shown there is nothing more specific you do with the event.